# Bolding ListView items at runtime does not work in Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

This code works in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but not in Delphi Toyko 10.2.3:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if item.Caption='Item2' then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := Sender.Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  end
  else
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := Sender.Canvas.Font.Style - [fsBold]
end;
```

The red font color still works, but the style has stopped having any effect.

Am I supposed to be doing something different now?

Comment: Bug: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20231